# How to properly create an instance to use methods?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to wrap my head around classes. This is probably a newbie question, but considering I keep googling and am stuck in a circle I guess I need a pointer.

The problem is that im trying to create an instance so that I may use the methods of Info and Liste by button click in winforms. However, it tells me that

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter
>   of form1.

Which makes sense, considering its an constructor and all.

As potential fix its telling me to use the following code in the `Methods` class:

```
public Methods()
{
}
```

Which is another constructor I take it, however I have 0 idea what to do with it. Help is appreciated.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    Methods Methods = new Methods(); // not working

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Methods Methods = new Methods(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Methods.Info();  // not working
        Methods.Liste(); // not working
    }       
}

public class Methods
{
    int count = 0;
    private Main mainForm;

    public Methods(Main form1)
    {
        mainForm = form1;
    }

    public void Info()
    {
        Inventory.array[count] = Convert.ToInt32(mainForm.textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(mainForm.textBox3.Text);
        count++;
    }

    public void Liste()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int i in Inventory.array)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        mainForm.label5.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. As a general tip, you should read the error messages and fix those. "Not working" is not all that helpful and we're left with trying to decipher what you mean by "not working". You can start by fixing the field initialization, where you're calling the constructor, but not passing `this`. You cannot pass `this`, so move the initialization code into the constructor.

Comment: Your `Methods` constructor: `Methods(Main form1)` - it requires that you pass an instance of `Main` to it. Your call to the construtor: `Methods Methods = new Methods();`

Comment: `Methods Methods = ...` may lead to confusion. `Methods.someMethod();` am I calling something static or instancied? I'd rather name it `Methods methods = ...` to avoid such confusions (notice the lowercase). Plus a method is a specific term for *functions inside a class*.

Comment: Just don't initialize the field in its declaration.  You are already doing it correctly in the form constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors. Let´s focus them step by step:

1. You have a field of type `Methods` that references the single instance of your `Methods`-class (by the way a really **bad** name for a **class**). In order to create that instance you need a reference to an existing form. However the `this`-keyword doesn´t exist outside a member. That´s what the compilercomplains about in your field-declaration.
2. You have a **local** variable named `Methods` in your constructor that *hides* the field. So in fact you have two instances of the class, one in the field, and one defined in the cosntructor. Just omit the latter:

   ```
   readonly Methods Methods;

   public Main()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Methods = new Methods(this);
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Methods.Info();  // not working
       Methods.Liste(); // not working
   }
   ```

   Just an aside: you can omit the `this`-keyword in the constructor:

   ```
   Methods = new Methods(this)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   this.Methods = new Methods(this)
   ```

   as it´s clear to which symbol you refer. I only added it to make this more clear.
3. Most important: `Methods` is really bad name for a class. Instead chose a name that describes what your class is supposed to do. Best you have a look at [naming-conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

```
Methods Methods = new Methods(this);
```

is creating a local variable that shadows the field in the class. Use

```
this.Methods = new Methods(this);
```

instead. And you should not use capitalized words for fields or locals.